# Latent Semantic Analysis results

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svd, sklearn-pandas, lsa

I'm following a tutorial for LSA and having switched the example to a different list of strings, I'm not sure the  code is working as expected.

When I use the example-input as given in the tutorial, it produces sensible answers. However when I use my own inputs, I'm getting very strange results.

For comparison, here's the results for the example-input:

[image]

When I use my own examples, this is the result. Also worth noting I don't seem to be getting consistent results:

[image]

[image]

Any help in figuring out why I'm getting these results would be greatly appreciated :)

Here's the code:

```
import sklearn
# Import all of the scikit learn stuff
from __future__ import print_function
from sklearn.decomposition import TruncatedSVD
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.preprocessing import Normalizer
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans, MiniBatchKMeans
import pandas as pd
import warnings
# Suppress warnings from pandas library
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=DeprecationWarning,
module="pandas", lineno=570)
import numpy


example = ["Coffee brewed by expressing or forcing a small amount of 
nearly boiling water under pressure through finely ground coffee 
beans.", 
"An espresso-based coffee drink consisting of espresso with 
microfoam (steamed milk with small, fine bubbles with a glossy or 
velvety consistency)", 
"American fast-food dish, consisting of french fries covered in 
cheese with the possible addition of various other toppings", 
"Pounded and breaded chicken is topped with sweet honey, salty 
dill pickles, and vinegar-y iceberg slaw, then served upon crispy 
challah toast.", 
"A layered, flaky texture, similar to a puff pastry."]

''''
example = ["Machine learning is super fun",
"Python is super, super cool",
"Statistics is cool, too",
"Data science is fun",
"Python is great for machine learning",
"I like football",
"Football is great to watch"]
'''

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(min_df = 1, stop_words = 'english')
dtm = vectorizer.fit_transform(example)
pd.DataFrame(dtm.toarray(),index=example,columns=vectorizer.get_feature_names()).head(10)

# Get words that correspond to each column
vectorizer.get_feature_names()

# Fit LSA. Use algorithm = “randomized” for large datasets
lsa = TruncatedSVD(2, algorithm = 'arpack')
dtm_lsa = lsa.fit_transform(dtm.astype(float))
dtm_lsa = Normalizer(copy=False).fit_transform(dtm_lsa)

pd.DataFrame(lsa.components_,index = ["component_1","component_2"],columns = vectorizer.get_feature_names())

pd.DataFrame(dtm_lsa, index = example, columns = "component_1","component_2"])

xs = [w[0] for w in dtm_lsa]
ys = [w[1] for w in dtm_lsa]
xs, ys

# Plot scatter plot of points
%pylab inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
figure()
plt.scatter(xs,ys)
xlabel('First principal component')
ylabel('Second principal component')
title('Plot of points against LSA principal components')
show()

#Plot scatter plot of points with vectors
%pylab inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure()
ax = plt.gca()
ax.quiver(0,0,xs,ys,angles='xy',scale_units='xy',scale=1, linewidth = .01)
ax.set_xlim([-1,1])
ax.set_ylim([-1,1])
xlabel('First principal component')
ylabel('Second principal component')
title('Plot of points against LSA principal components')
plt.draw()
plt.show()

# Compute document similarity using LSA components
similarity = np.asarray(numpy.asmatrix(dtm_lsa) * 
numpy.asmatrix(dtm_lsa).T)
pd.DataFrame(similarity,index=example, columns=example).head(10)
```

Comment: To get reproducible results, you should add the `random_state` param in TruncatedSVD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem looks like it's due to a combination of the small number of examples you're using, and the normalisation step. Because the `TrucatedSVD` maps your count vector to lots of very small numbers and one comparatively large number, when you normalise these you see some strange behaviour. You can see this by looking at a scatter plot of your data.

```
dtm_lsa = lsa.fit_transform(dtm.astype(float))
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i in range(dtm_lsa.shape[0]):
    ax.scatter(dtm_lsa[i, 0], dtm_lsa[i, 1], label=f'{i+1}')
ax.legend()
```

[image: not normalised]

I would say that this plot represents your data, as the two coffee examples are out of the way to the right (hard to say much else with a small number of examples). However when you normalise the data

```
dtm_lsa = lsa.fit_transform(dtm.astype(float))
dtm_lsa = Normalizer(copy=False).fit_transform(dtm_lsa)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i in range(dtm_lsa.shape[0]):
    ax.scatter(dtm_lsa[i, 0], dtm_lsa[i, 1], label=f'{i+1}')
ax.legend()
```

[image: normalised]

This pushes some points on top of each other which will give you similarities of `1`. The issue will almost certainly disappear the more variance there is, i.e. the more new samples you add.